# Percentage of two numbers and show final result in another td

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that consists of tr and tds and I show the percentage of sold ticket in third td.My code has problem whenever I write "Mytext" instead of number and calculate wrong moreover it shows infinity instead of showing write percentage. How can I define if the td has "mytext" instead of number , set the  closest number in sold column instead of that text and then calculate ?For instance if there was Mytext in avalable column and 5 in sold column replace 5 with text and then calculate ?
here is my code :

```js
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
  var $this = this,
    td2Value = $('td:nth-child(2)', $this).text().trim().split(/\D+/);

  $('span.result', $this).each(function (index, element) {
    let v = $('td:nth-child(1)', $this).text().trim().split(/\D+/);
    $(element).html(Math.round((td2Value[index] * 100 / v[index]) || 0) + '%');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th> avalable</th>
                  <th> sold</th>
                  <th>  result </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
Mytext<br>  
10<br/> 
</td>
<td>
5<br/>
2<br/>
</td>
<td>
<span class="result"></span><br/>
<span class="result"></span><br/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the regex number in `available` column, then check for the value if it equals `Mytext` change it

```js
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
  var $this = this,
    td2Value = $('td:nth-child(2)', $this).text().trim().split(/\D+/);

  $('span.result', $this).each(function (index, element) {
    //change starts here
    let v = $('td:nth-child(1)', $this).text().trim().split(/\r?\n/);
    if(v[index] != null && v[index].trim() == "Mytext")
    {
       v[index] = td2Value[index];
    }
    if(v[index] != null )
    {
      $(element).html(Math.round((td2Value[index] * 100 / v[index]) || 0) + '%');
    }
    //change ends here
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th> avalable</th>
                  <th> sold</th>
                  <th>  result </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
Mytext<br>  
10<br/> 
</td>
<td>
5<br/>
2<br/>
</td>
<td>
<span class="result"></span><br/>
<span class="result"></span><br/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked for me.But i have a question, in some cases i have only a value in each td. in this case the code has error and it does not calculate the next row value percentage

Comment: yes , for example before this tr I have another tr and in that tr I have only mytext as avalable column and 5 as sold column and  I dont have another number. in this case the code has error

Comment: replace following in each : 
let v = $('td:nth-child(1)', $this).text().trim().split(/\r?\n/);
        if(v[index] != null && v[index].trim() == "Mytext")
        {
           v[index] = td2Value[index];
        }
  if(v[index] != null )
  {
        $(element).html(Math.round((td2Value[index] * 100 / v[index]) || 0) + '%');
  }
 and tell me if it works